# Which Class has to be reimplemented for custom Selection in QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, qtgui, qt4.8

QTableWidget consists of several Selection Modi, which are selectable with the method

```
setSelectionMode (QAbstractItemView::SelectionMode mode)
```

None of the given modi fits the type of interactive selection i want to have. I want to implement a selection mode where when a user clicks in one table cell, and then shift+clicks in another table cell, the resulting selection is not a sum of columns and rows between these two, but starts from the first clicked cell, goes in read direction along row by row, ending by the second click. I hope i made clear what i want to do.

Do i need to overwrite the QItemSelectionModel or the QTableWidget? 
Where are the user clicks for selection are processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a descendant of QItemSelectionModel and reimplement `select`.

```
virtual void select(const QModelIndex & index, QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags command)
virtual void select(const QItemSelection & selection, QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags command)
```

When reimplementing `select` you can call `QItemSelectionModel::select` with different arguments to achieve the needed result.

Then assign an instance of the selection model to `QTableWidget` with `setItemSelectionModel`.